# Accuracy given from evaluating model not equal to sklearn classification_report accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I'm using sklearn classification_report for reporting test statistics. The accuracy given by this method is 42% while model evaluation gives 93% accuracy. Which one is the real accuracy and what's the reason of this difference?

Model evaluation:
`results = model.evaluate(test_ds.values, test_lb.values)
print(results)` 
Output:
`7397/7397 [==============================] - 0s 28us/sample - loss: 0.2309 - acc: 0.9305`
Report Classification:
`import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
predictions = model.predict(test_ds)
print(classification_report(test_lb, np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)))`
Output:

`label    precision   recall   f1-score    support`

```
       0       0.41      0.38      0.40      3700
       1       0.43      0.46      0.44      3697

accuracy                           0.42      7397
```

Comment: What is the output layer of your model and the loss function you are using?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro - two neurons layer using sigmoid as activation function. Binary crossentropyis used as loss function.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm currently having the same issue and I'm pretty frustrated.

Comment: @ZarifAzher - I implemented the network again from scratch and the problem got solved.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, both the metrics should give the accuracy of the same level with some minor difference. The problem may be with the data.

You can see the below example to compare both the Metrics.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, (2, 3)] # petal length, petal width
y = (iris.target == 0).astype(np.int) 

(X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test) = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[2]),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, kernel_initializer="he_normal"),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=2)
```

**Training Accuracy:**

```
Epoch 1/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 2.0655 - accuracy: 0.6333
Epoch 2/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5199 - accuracy: 0.7333
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fdd4ed72048>
```

**Evaluation Result:**

```
test_ds = pd.DataFrame(X_test)
test_lb = pd.DataFrame(y_test)
model.evaluate(test_ds.values,test_lb.values)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.5510 - accuracy: 0.6667
[0.5510352253913879, 0.6666666865348816]
```

**With Sklearn Metrics:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, np.argmax(predictions, axis=1))) 

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.67      1.00      0.80        20
           1       0.00      0.00      0.00        10

    accuracy                           0.67        30
   macro avg       0.33      0.50      0.40        30
weighted avg       0.44      0.67      0.53        30
```

You can see the accuracy is the same for both metrics(66.7 & 67).